# Psycopg2 access PostgreSQL database on remote host without manually opening ssh tunnel

Tags: python, database, postgresql, ssh, psycopg2

My standard procedure for accessing a PostgreSQL database on a remote server is to first create an ssh tunnel as:

```
ssh username1@remote.somewhere.com -L 5432:localhost:5432 -p 222
```

and then run my query in python from another shell as:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost" + " dbname=" +
                         conf.dbname + " user=" + conf.user + 
                         " password=" + conf.password)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(query)
```

This piece of python code works nicely once the tunnel is created. However, I would like psycopg2 to already open the SSH tunnel or reach "somehow" the remote database without need to redirect it on my localhost.

Is it possible to do this with psycopg2?

Is otherwise possible open the ssh tunnel in my python code?

if I use:

```
os.system("ssh username1@remote.somewhere.com -L 5432:localhost:5432 -p 222")
```

The shell will be redirected to the remote host blocking the execution of main thread.

Comment: Why not just use SSL on the remote PostgreSQL server, and connect with PostgreSQL's SSL support?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the moment I am using a solution bsed on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/carlohamalainen/3803816):

```
class SSHTunnel(object):
    """
    A context manager implementation of an ssh tunnel opened from python

    """


    def __init__(self, tunnel_command):

        assert "-fN" in tunnel_command, "need to open the tunnel with -fN"
        self._tunnel_command = tunnel_command
        self._delay = 0.1

    def create_tunnel(self):

        tunnel_cmd = self._tunnel_command
        import time, psutil, subprocess
        ssh_process = subprocess.Popen(tunnel_cmd,  universal_newlines=True,
                                                    shell=True,
                                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        # Assuming that the tunnel command has "-f" and "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes", then the
        # command will return immediately so we can check the return status with a poll().

        while True:
            p = ssh_process.poll()
            if p is not None: break
            time.sleep(self._delay)


        if p == 0:
            # Unfortunately there is no direct way to get the pid of the spawned ssh process, so we'll find it
            # by finding a matching process using psutil.

            current_username = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).username
            ssh_processes = [proc for proc in psutil.get_process_list() if proc.cmdline == tunnel_cmd.split() and proc.username == current_username]

            if len(ssh_processes) == 1:
                self.ssh_tunnel = ssh_processes[0]
                return ssh_processes[0]
            else:
                raise RuntimeError, 'multiple (or zero?) tunnel ssh processes found: ' + str(ssh_processes)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError, 'Error creating tunnel: ' + str(p) + ' :: ' + str(ssh_process.stdout.readlines())


    def release(self):
        """ Get rid of the tunnel by killin the pid
        """
        self.ssh_tunnel.terminate()


    def __enter__(self):
        self.create_tunnel()
        return self


    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):

        self.release()


    def __del__(self):
        self.release()


def test():
    #do things that will fail if the tunnel is not opened

    print "done =========="


command = "ssh username@someserver.com -L %d:localhost:%d -p 222 -fN" % (someport, someport)

with SSHTunnel(command):
    test()
```

Please let me know if anybody has a better idea

Comment: Isn't there an error in the script? ssh_tunnel hasn't been defined before.

Answer (score 22):

You could also use [sshtunnel](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel), short and sweet:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

PORT=5432
with SSHTunnelForwarder((REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_SSH_PORT),
         ssh_username=REMOTE_USERNAME,
         ssh_password=REMOTE_PASSWORD,
         remote_bind_address=('localhost', PORT),
         local_bind_address=('localhost', PORT)):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of using private key with passphrase?  I can't see an example anywhere.

Comment: @rishabh-sagar, use `ssh_pkey` and `ssh_private_key_password` keyword arguments as documented in https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. E.g. `SSHTunnelForwarder(..., ssh_pkey='/path/to/keyfile', ssh_private_key_password='secret', ...)`

Comment: The current import syntax is `from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder`

Answer (score 4):

**With sshtunnel package**

I was not familiar with SSH tunnels, so I had some difficulties to use mrts's answer.
Maybe thoses precisions could help someone.

In psycopg2.connect(), host and port are the one you just created by connecting remote host by ssh tunnel.

Here is my code :

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder((REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_SSH_PORT),
         ssh_username=REMOTE_USERNAME,
         ssh_password=REMOTE_PASSWORD,
         remote_bind_address=('localhost', PORT),
         local_bind_address=('localhost', PORT))
server.start()

import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=DATABASE,
    user=USER,
    host=server.local_bind_host,
    port=server.local_bind_port,
    password=PWD)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from yourtable limit 1;")
data = cur.fetchall()
print(data)
```

I hope this example make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Call your ssh via `os.system` in a separate thread/process. You can also use `-N` with ssh to avoid opening a remote shell.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution sometimes works sometimes does not depending on the time to create the tunnel

Comment: This is a normal race condition. Run `ssh` with `-v` using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system` and wait for the ssh output when it says "Local forwarding listening" in the output. Use a [`threading.Event`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) to synchronize the caller with the callee.

Answer (score 0):

Clodoaldo Neto's code worked for me perfectly but beware it doesn't clean up the process afterward.

The method shown by Luca Fiaschi also works for me. I updated it a bit for python3 and the updated psutil module. The changes were just that process.username and process.cmdline are now functions and that the iterator is process_iter() instead of get_process_list().

Here is an example of a very slightly modified version of the code Luca Fiaschi posted that works with python3 (requires psutil module). I hope it is at least mostly correct!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psutil
import psycopg2
import subprocess
import time
import os

# Tunnel Config
SSH_HOST = "111.222.333.444"
SSH_USER = "user"
SSH_KEYFILE = "key.pem"
SSH_FOREIGN_PORT = 5432   # Port that postgres is running on the foreign server
SSH_INTERNAL_PORT = 5432  # Port we open locally that is forwarded to
                          # FOREIGN_PORT on the server.

# Postgres Config
DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
DB_PORT = SSH_INTERNAL_PORT
DB_PASSWORD = "password"
DB_DATABASE = "postgres"
DB_USER = "user"

class SSHTunnel(object):
    """
    A context manager implementation of an ssh tunnel opened from python

    """
    def __init__(self, tunnel_command):
        assert "-fN" in tunnel_command, "need to open the tunnel with -fN"
        self._tunnel_command = tunnel_command
        self._delay = 0.1
        self.ssh_tunnel = None

    def create_tunnel(self):
        tunnel_cmd = self._tunnel_command
        ssh_process = subprocess.Popen(tunnel_cmd, universal_newlines=True,
            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        # Assuming that the tunnel command has "-f" and "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes", then the
        # command will return immediately so we can check the return status with a poll().

        while True:
            p = ssh_process.poll()
            if p is not None: break
            time.sleep(self._delay)


        if p == 0:
            # Unfortunately there is no direct way to get the pid of the spawned ssh process, so we'll find it
            # by finding a matching process using psutil.

            current_username = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).username()
            ssh_processes = [proc for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.cmdline() == tunnel_cmd.split() and proc.username() == current_username]

            if len(ssh_processes) == 1:
                self.ssh_tunnel = ssh_processes[0]
                return ssh_processes[0]
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('multiple (or zero?) tunnel ssh processes found: ' + str(ssh_processes))
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Error creating tunnel: ' + str(p) + ' :: ' + str(ssh_process.stdout.readlines()))

    def release(self):
        """ Get rid of the tunnel by killin the pid
        """
        if self.ssh_tunnel:
            self.ssh_tunnel.terminate()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.create_tunnel()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.release()

    def __del__(self):
        self.release()

command = "ssh -i %s %s@%s -fNL %d:localhost:%d"\
    % (SSH_KEYFILE, SSH_USER, SSH_HOST, SSH_INTERNAL_PORT, SSH_FOREIGN_PORT)

with SSHTunnel(command):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host = DB_HOST, password = DB_PASSWORD,
                     database = DB_DATABASE, user = DB_USER, port = DB_PORT)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    sql = "select * from table"
    curs.execute(sql)
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    print(rows)
```

Comment: I get an attribute error when I try to execute the script. "SSHTunnel" has no attribute 'ssh_tunnel'. Please help.

Comment: It looks like the only time self.ssh_tunnel is accessed is in SSHTunnel.release. If that variable doesn't exist, I bet self.ssh_tunnel isn't getting set which means ssh_processes isn't filling with any processes. How are you invoking ssh (the variable "command") and does invoking that command by itself in a shell execute? Also, I'll edit the script to make it not error.

Answer (score 0):

### Connect to AWS/GCP/Azure Through Bastion Tunnel

I got very confused about where to put TUNNEL credentials and where to put AWS/GCP/Azure bits, so here is a working example (using `with` statements for better maintainability).

```py
import os

import psycopg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

load_dotenv()

# Setting up the SSH tunnel with tunnel credentials
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ssh_address_or_host=(os.environ.get("TUNNEL_HOST"), int(os.environ.get("TUNNEL_PORT"))),
    ssh_username=os.environ.get("TUNNEL_USERNAME"),
    ssh_pkey=os.environ.get("TUNNEL_PRIVATE_KEY"),
    # Key part! Connect to AWS_HOST through the tunnel.
    remote_bind_address=(os.environ.get("AWS_HOST"), int(os.environ.get("AWS_PORT"))),
    # The port doesn't matter, but pick AWS_PORT for ease.
    local_bind_address=("localhost", int(os.environ.get("AWS_PORT")))
) as server:
    # Connect to the database using AWS credentials
    with psycopg2.connect(
        database=os.environ.get("AWS_DATABASE"),
        user=os.environ.get("AWS_USER"),
        password=os.environ.get("AWS_PASSWORD"),
        # Key part! You connect through the server!
        host=server.local_bind_host,
        port=server.local_bind_port,
    ) as conn:
        # Run SQL queries
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2;")
            data = cur.fetchall()
            print(data)
```

Some notes:

- I'm using `python-dotenv` library since you'll usually store credentials in a .env file.
- Assuming you use a private key to connect to the tunnel and password to connect to AWS. You can change `ssh_pkey` to `ssh_password` in `SSHTunnelForwarder` and `password` to `sslkey` in `psycopg2.connect` if you require something different.
- You must do `int(os.environ.get("TUNNEL_PORT"))` because everything in .env files is a string.
- `data` is a list of tuples

Answer (score -3):

```
from time import sleep

os.system("ssh username1@remote.somewhere.com -fNL 5432:localhost:5432 -p 222")

while True:
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            "host=localhost dbname={0} user={1} password={2}".format(
                conf.dbname, conf.user, conf.password
            )
        )
        break
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        sleep(3)
```

Comment: Does not execute or give back any input from the "conn = psycopg2.connect()" part.

Comment: @SirBenBenji There is nothing to be executed in this answer. The only thing it does is to establish an ssh connection and connect to the database as asked. What were you expecting?

Comment: It does not connect to the database on my system, or I am geting no feedback from your solution. Cursor just blinks and we are "caught" in "-N". I went with subprocess. os.system can be considered obsolete.